# Acer Extensa does not suspend when closed on 13.04, worked on 12.10

Tags: suspend

I have an Acer Extensa 5635G

Running Ubuntu 12.10, if I close the notebook, then it goes into sleep mode automatically, but on Ubuntu 13.04 this doesn't work. The notebook keeps running after I close the display.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Check out the power settings Under System Settings, and check the settings.

[image]

[image]